# HTTP POST in GROOVY

Tags: groovy, soap, http-post, soapui, camunda

I'm trying desperately to translate this python code into groovy, but I can't find the right solution.

It could be great if someone could help me a bit. :)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import requests

url = "http://localhost:8088/mockServiceSoapBinding"

xml = '''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sam="http://www.soapui.org/sample/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <sam:login>
 <username>Login</username>
 <password>Login123</password>
 </sam:login>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''

headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate'}

r1 = requests.post(url, data=xml, headers=headers, auth=('user', 'pass'))

print(r1.text)
```

Comment: type `groovy http post` in search box and you'll have a lot of examples...

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

Making HTTP POST call from Groovy can be done by initializing the URL connection.

Here is a working example:

```groovy
url = 'http://localhost:8088/mockServiceSoapBinding'

def username = 'user'
def password = 'pass'

xml = '''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sam="http://www.soapui.org/sample/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <sam:login>
 <username>Login</username>
 <password>Login123</password>
 </sam:login>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''

def connection = new URL(url).openConnection()
connection.setRequestMethod('POST')

// set headers
connection.setRequestProperty('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8')
connection.setRequestProperty('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate')

if (username && password) {
    String userCredentials = username + ':' + password
    String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes())
    connection.setRequestProperty('Authorization', basicAuth)
}

connection.doOutput = true
connection.outputStream.write(xml.getBytes('UTF-8'))

println "XX: connect"
connection.connect()

println "XX: get content"
def text = connection.content.text

println(text)
```